# AWS AppSync resolver internal timeout configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

Given the scenario that I am using a simple vtl resolver for either http or dynamodb, is there a way to e.g. execute some cleanup in case of the data source timing out (e.g. the dynamodb service not responding in let's say 2s). I can't find any reference of appsync and timeout anywhere on the internet unfortunately, and I would like to be able to:
1. specify a lower threshold timeout for resolvers that is lower than the default appsync timeout of 30 seconds
2. be able to have a fallback mechanism in the case of the aforementioned timeout

I think that should be easy to do with a lambda resolver, but at the moment I am trying to avoid that because of cold starts.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work on the AWS AppSync team.  AWS AppSync does not currently support custom timeout values for resolvers or a fallback mechanism when timeouts occur.  As you mentioned, a lambda resolver is the best option right now if you require this functionality.

I will pass this along as a feature request.  It would be helpful to know what sort of things you are wanting to do as part of the cleanup process for HTTP and DynamoDB resolvers.

Comment: Well not really cleanup but let's say that I want to pass back from the resolver a certain default state in case of a timeout. Or maybe pipe in to another function to be executed.

Comment: A good example would be say that for a vehicle registration lookup within our site, we will be using a third party http endpoint. If the service does not respond within e.g. 2 seconds, I would like the site to instead display a manual lookup functionality so that the user can input the details themselves. Or maybe retry if the service has not responded in 2 seconds. Then again, this can be done with timeout from the client side.

Comment: Maybe a better example in which client timeout would not work would be having a pipe resolver for the vehicle registration lookup inside AppSync. In case of using 2 third party providers I would like to fallback to the second one if the first one is slower than 2 seconds. Doing this server side with AppSync resolver timeouts would save me a roundtrip from the client. And I would like to avoid lambda because of the unfortunate cold starts, which seem to be quite ok in AppSync using vtl resolvers.